# Codeigniter Send Separate Emails Simultaneously

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Using Codeigniter 3, I have a web form that sends an email to the site admin once a form is submitted - this works as expected.

I am using email templates, once the form is submitted *template 1* is sent (to the site admin). I would now like to simultaneously send *template 2* (to the submitter's email address).

The emails will contain the same content *apart from* the email intro text, and subject - details below;

- Email Template 1 - to **admin**;

*'Hi, a new item has been requested on the site, ...'*

- Email Template 2 - to **submitter**;

*'Hi, Here is the item you have requested on the site, ...'*

My current code is as follows;

```
public function sendRequest() {

    $this->load->library('email');

    $from_email     = $this->input->post('email'); 
    $to_email       = 'admin@example.com'; 
    $subject        = 'New Item Request - Admin Copy';
    $name           = $this->input->post('name'); 
    $comment        = $this->input->post('comment');

    $this->email->from($from_email); 
    $this->email->to($to_email);
    $this->email->subject($subject); 

    $data = array(
        'name'          =>  $name,
        'from'          =>  $from_email,
        'comment'       =>  $comment,
        );
    // send email template 1
    $this->email->message($this->load->view('template/email/item_request_template', $data, true));

   // send email template 2 to submitter - how?
   // change $subject to 'New Item Request - User Copy';

    if($this->email->send()) {
        // send the $data to my email template
        $data = array(
         'item_request_name'    => $this->input->post('name'),
         'item_request_email'   => $this->input->post('email'),
         'item_request_comment' => $this->input->post('comment'),
         );
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: since you've 2 different recipients with different contents, you've to send it separately- the only thing which comes to mind - maybe you can try to make an own mail controller who handles the entire mail sending process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to repeat all the steps required for sending an email in the first place. Only difference is that for the second call you need to call, and reset all the required config options.

```
public function sendRequest() {

   $this->load->library('email');

   $from_email     = $this->input->post('email');
   $to_email       = 'admin@example.com';
   $subject        = 'New Item Request - Admin Copy';
   $name           = $this->input->post('name');
   $comment        = $this->input->post('comment');

   $this->email->from($from_email);
   $this->email->to($to_email);
   $this->email->subject($subject);

   $data = array(
       'name'          =>  $name,
       'from'          =>  $from_email,
       'comment'       =>  $comment,
       );
   // send email template 1
   $this->email->message($this->load->view('template/email/item_request_template', $data, true));

  // send email template 2 to submitter - how?
  // change $subject to 'New Item Request - User Copy';

   if($this->email->send()) {

       $this->email->clear(TRUE); // Pass TRUE as an argument if you are sending attachments

       $this->email->from($from_email); // Update for second email
       $this->email->to($to_email); // Update for second email
       $this->email->subject($subject); // Update for second email

       // send the $data to my email template
       $data = array(
        'item_request_name'    => $this->input->post('name'),
        'item_request_email'   => $this->input->post('email'),
        'item_request_comment' => $this->input->post('comment'),
        );

       $this->email->message($this->load->view('template/email/item_request_template_2', $data, true));

       $this->email->send();
   }
}
```